# ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/source/src/tsconfig.json' - angular-cli

Tags: angular, deployment, angular-cli

I m using deploybot tool to deploy my angular site from bitbucket to AWS S3, it used to work fine earlier but now I have upgrade from angular 2 to angular 4.1.2 and angular-cli@latest => 1.0.0

after npm install in deploybot my file structure is

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 999 1295 May 10 09:59 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1002 2770 May 27 09:35 tslint.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1002 385 May 27 09:35 tsconfig.json
drwxr-xr-x 5 1001 999 4096 May 27 09:35 src
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1002 756 May 27 09:35 protractor.conf.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1002 1785 May 27 09:35 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1002 1240 May 27 09:35 karma.conf.js
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 999 4096 May 27 09:35 e2e
drwxrwxrwx 773 root root 20480 May 27 09:38 node_modules
```

My error:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (1.0.6) is greater than your local
output version (1.0.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.
output To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
output ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/source/src/tsconfig.json'
output Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/source/src/tsconfig.json'
output at Error (native)
output at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:987:18)
output at AotPlugin._setupOptions (/source/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:58:16)
output at new AotPlugin (/source/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:26:14)
output at _createAotPlugin (/source/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:55:12)
output at Object.exports.getAotConfig (/source/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:89:19)
output at NgCliWebpackConfig.buildConfig (/source/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-config.js:26:37)
output at Class.run (/source/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/build.js:26:92)
output at Class.run (/source/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/build.js:143:26)
output at Class.Command.validateAndRun (/source/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:128:15)
output at /source/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:92:22
output at tryCatch (/source/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:539:12)
output at invokeCallback (/source/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:554:13)
output at /source/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:629:16
output at flush (/source/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2414:5)
output at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
```

I do understand that the location /source/src/tsconfig.json will not give him the required file, bcoz there is "tsconfig.app.json" and "tsconfig.json" is in root folder i.e /source

But what I am unable to understand is
1. why is my local environment able to build and serve properly and same thing is not working on deploybot deployment
2. which file/command in the ng build --prod - tells the system to search for tsconfig.json in the wrong path. so that I may correct it.

Comment: It might be because you moved your files into another directory, but you might forget the angular-cli file!

Comment: True... had the same issue and now fixed by copy `angular-cli.json` too.

Comment: You could look the same question, it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938391/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-in-tsconfig-app-json-using-angular-4/52719980#52719980