# ENOENT: no such file or directory in tsconfig.app.json using angular 4?

Tags: angular

I am using angular 4 and spring boot,while execute the project using command line..its showing error

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\AJITH VANUSTON\Spring Project\1Medeil Project\Project medeil RAR files\1gradle project\angular 4 boot\microservicesample-master\src\tsconfig.app.json'
```

Pls see below the Error Image

[image]

Comment: did you try "npm install" ?

Comment: yeah i tried but it was not solve

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Check the path for the **tsconfig** property in the **angular.json** file. Correcting that path should fix this error.

```
"architect":{
  ....
  ....
  ....
  "tsConfig": "apps/projectName/tsconfig.app.json",
  ....
  ....
  ....
}
```

Comment: there is no such file present in my project, tsconfig.app.json

Comment: search for `tsConfig` key in angular.json, that is the file, name need not to be exact.

Comment: I have same problem. my angular-cli version `~9.1.1`.
when I run `npm start`, i got above error.
so I changed `tsConfig` in `angular.json` file, but the error is same.

Comment: @RV There is no file in my project, I have checked all the directories, do I need to create a new file? If yes then what should this file have?

Answer (score 4):

I researched this issue for the solution: Your Angular project has a tsconfig.app.json. This file is being specified in your .angular-cli.json file.

You could control your app src structure according to below structure.

Your app lives in the src folder:

```
src
  -app
  -assets
  -environments
  -browserslist
  -favicon.ico
  -index.html
  -karma.conf.js
  -main.ts
  -polyfills.ts
  -styles.css
  -test.ts
  -tsconfig.app.json
  -tsconfig.spec.json
  -tslint.json
```

You could check your project src.

References:

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8201
- https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Answer (score 1):

Ionic throws this error when you are in a different folder by accident and run the build process. It will not tell you you're in a non-project folder, it just throws this error...

Comment: Go to the root folder of your project and run from there

Comment: I got this bug. But seems like i was not able to fix the same i feel like i am running `ionic lab` command from the root folder but its still didnt frixed it. Can you show me the path of the root which you are refering to?

Answer (score 1):

Cut out the tsconfig.app.json file from src folder and paste it into your main folder (means where you have src , e2e ,etc files are there )
Easy to say paste it in one directory back.