# Export Angular project from StackBlitz to local

Tags: angular, stackblitz

I would like to export an Angular project done in StackBlitz an execute it from Angular CLI with the command `ng serve`as we do with an Angular project created in our local machines.

Answer (score 82):

Just do it. Here is where you need to click:

[image: stackblitz screenshot]

Comment: Thankyou so much. That was what I was looking for

Comment: Changed to cloud download now, same place. see Sathia's answer below.

Answer (score 37):

See here. Using this button, you can download the source code.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

To resolve this error:
    ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/.../projectFolder/tsconfig.app.json'

After downloading the project from StackBlitz I copied the zip to a folder.
The tsconfig.app.json file for my project was located in the src folder.
To resolve the error above I replaced the property `"tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json"` with `"tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json"` in my angular.json file.
In the terminal I ran `npm install` in the project's directory to install all the dependencies.
I then ran `ng serve -o` to run the server and the app opened up in my browser successfully.

source: [ENOENT: no such file or directory in tsconfig.app.json using angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938391/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-in-tsconfig-app-json-using-angular-4)

Edit:
The Building Locally section of https://angular.io/start/deployment gives instructions on how to build a StackBlitz application locally. It basically says to install the Angular CLI, create a new project, replace the /src folder in your new project with the /src folder from the downloaded StackBlitz project, and finally build the project.

This however did not work for me as it caused a missing Module error. What did work was replacing all the files in the new project folder that matched the files from the StackBlitz project folder. Run `npm install`, `npm build --prod`, and finally `ng serve -o`.

Comment: changing the tsConfig is the way to go

Comment: This solution (the first two paragraphs) worked for me with the current tools versions as of this date. I do get a warning "Your global Angular CLI version (8.3.3) is greater than your local version (7.0.7). The local Angular CLI version is used.", but it works and shouldn't matter for an elementary learning project.

Comment: To build locally when you get this error, it's because Stackblitz doesn't give you all the files you need for angular apps.

You have to do the scaffolding with :

ng new project-name

Replace "project-name" with your desired project name.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

1. Click on that button with the arrow pointing down
2. cd into you project cd "your app name"
3. npm install
4. ng serve

Comment: I already tried that and I get `ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/lorenzo/Code/app2909/src/tsconfig.app.json'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/lorenzo/Code/app2909/src/tsconfig.app.json'`

Comment: did you make sure you are cd into app2909?

Comment: sure. And those files don't exists

Comment: try this npm install -g typescript

Comment: This file is being specified in your .angular-cli.json file. Make sure you have the path right as it's necessary for building the project.

Comment: It's not working. It's like those file aren't generated by Stackblitz

Comment: i'm literally having the same issue as you

Comment: I see it just downloads the files but not of it's dependencies

Answer (score 3):

I was also trying to export a StackBlitz Angular project to my local environment but ran into some different errors (e.g. `Error: Error on worker #1: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined`) -- probably due to missing files needed by my local CLI.

The [Running Your App Locally section](https://angular.io/start/start-deployment#running-your-application-locally) of the Angular docs (also pointed out in @HelloWorldPeace's answer), worked for me. To summarize:

1. Download the project zip from StackBlitz.
2. Create a blank local Angular project with the CLI: `ng new my-project-name`
3. Replace the `/src` folder of the new project with the `/src` folder of the StackBlitz download
4. `npm install` inside the project directory and `ng serve` (or `npm start`)

The Angular CLI caught some typing errors in strict mode that I had to fix (didn't have to worry about them in StackBlitz), but other than that everything was working properly.

Answer (score 2):

As @gal007, @tamo-studio and @jb-nizet pointed out, you should be able to just download the project, run `npm install` and `ng serve`, but this might not work for all projects.

It should work for any project with a current Angular version newer than version 6, I tried with v7 and it worked like a charm.

Your error message in one comment suggests the file `tsconfig.json` is missing, which you can take form a newly generated project of Angular. To create such a project follow these steps:

1. Check in `package.json` which version of Angular your current project uses (look for `@angular/core`)
2. install the corresponding version of the `angular-cli`, e. g. for v4 via `npm i -g @angular/cli@^4`
3. run `$ ng init` in an empty directory
4. Take the `tsconfig.json`, move it to your current project and make adjustments if required
5. Now you can delete the temporairly created project

This should make it run. If it does still not work, look at StackOverflow for the error messages or start a new Question :)

Answer (score 1):

It is true that StackBlitz does not generate such file. But a tsconfig.json file in a directory indicates that such directory is the root of a TypeScript project. So, you can create such file and leave it empty. It allowed me to compile from terminal. 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html